# My app dont receive push messages whem cel reboot or app is closed

Tags: android, service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that should receive push messages even with it closed. in my manifest I created a service as described in the google doc:

```
        <service android:name="br.com.melhordosgames.apk.services.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:directBootAware="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

In my class I extend it normally to the firebase message service

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
```

and I have an `onMessageReceive` inside that class to send the notification

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
```

But this only works with the app open or in the background it doesn't work, for example, if the phone has been restarted or if the app has been closed.

I've already looked at the documentation, I found a lot of things out there but very complex, I couldn't implement it, could someone explain to me how this works so I can understand where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is your Messages is coming from backend?
if yes is your are updating token to backend for getting messaging ?

Or you have implemented refreshToken method properly.

Comment: This may be a device issue, This issue reproduces on multiple devices or it is specifically to a device? If the application is forced stopped or the notification are not allowed you may have issues with the FCM. Also on Android 13 you need Notification Permission.

Comment: multiple devices have the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive push notifications even when the app is closed or the device has been rebooted, you need to use a background service that runs continuously and is able to receive push notifications even when the app is not in the foreground.

The service you've described in your AndroidManifest.xml looks correct, you have set the android:directBootAware attribute to true, this is necessary for your service to run during the device's boot process.

It seems like you correctly created an extension of FirebaseMessagingService and implemented the onMessageReceived method. But the problem is that, the default behavior of FirebaseMessagingService is to stop running when the app is closed or in background.

The solution for this is, when the app is closed or in background, Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) won't be able to deliver a message to the app by calling onMessageReceived method of your FirebaseMessagingService. The message will be delivered to the system tray. To receive the message in onMessageReceived even when the app is closed or in background, you will have to use a foreground service which is a service that runs in the foreground, with a notification.

let me share you the code so that you can implement a foreground service to receive push notifications even when the app is closed or in background.

public class MyForegroundService extends Service {
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());

    // perform your task here

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private Notification createNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText("Running in the foreground")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    return builder.build();
}
```

}

Comment: thank you for your help i understand how it works now but i could not implement it on my code i dont have mutch knoledge in java android yet